# Is there a way to scale x due to a right justified graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

Say I have a graph based on the following data:

```
library(tidyverse)
a <- tibble(x=1:10, y=.75^x)
ggplot(a, aes(x=x, y = y))+
  geom_line()
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWTNn.png

This is obviously an exponential decay graph, which would mean technically speaking it's all "squished" to the left or left justified or whatever it's called, so to "unsquish it" it's clear I would add a scale_x_log10() function to it.

```
ggplot(a, aes(x=x, y = y))+
  geom_line()+
  scale_x_log10()
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cARTB.png

The problem I'm having is I want to do that for a graph that is right justified.

Example graph:

```
a <- tibble(x=1:10, y=x^10)
ggplot(a, aes(x=x, y = y))+
  geom_line()
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYElT.png

Is there a way to do this with ggplot?

Comment: Are you looking for `scale_y_log10()`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a different transformation for the x-axis, e.g.:

```
ggplot(a, aes(x=x, y = y))+ scale_x_continuous(trans = modulus_trans(2)) + geom_line()
```